# Square brackets in in the `description' of the theorem environment

Tags: environments

The following code works fine

```
\begin{theorem}[Euler] Blah
\end{theorem}
```

But whenever I try to use square brackets in the description I get an error.

```
\begin{theorem}[The set $[0, 1]$ is compact] Blah
\end{theorem}
```

Can anybody tell me how to avoid the error, please?

Comment: What about using `...{$[0, 1]$}...`?

Comment: @Sam: `[]` within optional argument [] brackets must be surrounded by `{}` pair.

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! @ChristianHupfer This was my first post on tex.stackexchange. In the future I will make sure to provide MWE's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass[paper=a4,12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amsthm}%

\newtheorem{MyTheorem}{Brontosaurs}


\begin{document}

\begin{MyTheorem}[The set {$[0,1]$} is compact]
\end{MyTheorem}

\begin{MyTheorem}[By Ann Elk {[Misses]}]
\par
Brontosaurs are thin at one end, thick in the middle and thin again at the other end.
\end{MyTheorem}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I hope the five remaining guys of MP does not sue me for using that line ;-)